# Circle div bar for rating html5 js

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Hi i was using a bar rating system in my page, it shows by percentage how many points does the usear has by a very simple php code
Examle:

```
if($points>50){
 $level = "Full User";
 $level_bar = "100%";
}
```

And by the time of load the bar showed 100%  filled with another color.

The problem now its doing the filled bar circular, i had the idea  of doing it with html5 and i failed, any idea how to do it?

im trying to get this to work:
[Circular rating bar](http://d.pr/i/XLSf)

Comment: You may be interested in [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5001002/995958).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A demo made with a canvas element : http://jsfiddle.net/x4pVy/

if you want to show a different percentage, just change the value stored on `data-completeness` attribute on `canvas`

the percentage value can be written inside the canvas (through `fillText()` function) or into another DOM element you could place over the canvas (with css)

Comment: +1 for that nice solution. Although I'd prefer a solution with vanilla html/css;) Can this be animated?

Comment: Thats perfect, one more question, can i put a gradient color to that.

Comment: ok i already did the gradient thanks that was exactly what i needed +1