# How to Program a Circular Progress Bar

Tags: user-interface, libgdx

I am programming a video game using LibGDX and I can't for the life of me figure out how to program a circular progress bar. This is not where the progress bar spins. This is where it will start out as a full ring and as each 1% of progress is made then 1% of the ring disappears in a circular fashion. I am not looking for code I am just looking for ideas of where to start. I understand that I could just display 100 images each rotated slightly and show and hide them as needed. This however seems very processor intensive to display 100 images. So I am looking for some other method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render a circular/radial progress bar in Libgdx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981852/how-to-render-a-circular-radial-progress-bar-in-libgdx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Search stackoverflow for a "Libgdx circular progress bar"
2. Find [How to render a circular/radial progress bar in Libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981852/how-to-render-a-circular-radial-progress-bar-in-libgdx)
3. Done