# Implementing circle progress bar in libGDX

Tags: animation, libgdx, progress-bar, geometry

I want to create a circle progress bar, that will look like [this](http://www.designrazor.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Pure-CSS-radial-progress-bar.jpg) using libgdx library. For now on I've created simple horizontal progressbar using different Images as layers overlapping themselfs and one of them resizing to simulate progress. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18002473/4776020) example, how to draw circle progress bar, but I don't understand how to use this implementation and how can I handle it. The `textureRegion` in constructor is the progress indicator? and I could not find the method responsible to set the actual progress.

EDIT: I've made my solution basic on [this implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUtOy1kgWCk). I put 3 layers which overlapping themselfs and whenever the middle layer swipe's the progress is showed. But Ive have a problem: whenever I try to resize my `ProgressCircle` instance it move down below the background layer.

```
public class ProgressCircle extends Image {

    public enum IntersectAt {
        NONE, TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    TextureRegion texture;

    PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch;

    Vector2 center;
    Vector2 centerTop;
    Vector2 leftTop;
    Vector2 leftBottom;
    Vector2 rightBottom;
    Vector2 rightTop;
    Vector2 progressPoint;

    float[] fv;


    IntersectAt intersectAt;
    private float PROGRESS_WIDTH=0f;
    private float PROGRESS_HEIGHT=0f;
    private float posX,posY;

    public ProgressCircle(TextureRegion region, PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch,float width,float height,float posX,float posY) {
        super(region);
        PROGRESS_WIDTH=width;
        PROGRESS_HEIGHT=height;
        this.posX=posX;
        this.posY=posY;

        this.texture = region;
        this.polyBatch = polyBatch;

        center = new Vector2(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
        centerTop = new Vector2(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight());
        leftTop = new Vector2(0, this.getHeight());
        leftBottom = new Vector2(0, 0);
        rightBottom = new Vector2(this.getWidth(), 0);
        rightTop = new Vector2(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        progressPoint = new Vector2(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);

        setPercentage(0);
    }

    private Vector2 IntersectPoint(Vector2 line) {
        Vector2 v = new Vector2();
        boolean isIntersect;

        //check top
        isIntersect = Intersector.intersectSegments(leftTop, rightTop, center, line, v);

        //check bottom
        if (isIntersect) {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.TOP;
            return v;
        } else
            isIntersect = Intersector.intersectSegments(leftBottom, rightBottom, center, line, v);

        //check left
        if (isIntersect) {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.BOTTOM;
            return v;
        } else isIntersect = Intersector.intersectSegments(leftTop, leftBottom, center, line, v);

        //check bottom
        if (isIntersect) {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.LEFT;
            return v;
        } else isIntersect = Intersector.intersectSegments(rightTop, rightBottom, center, line, v);

        if (isIntersect) {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.RIGHT;
            return v;
        } else {
            intersectAt = IntersectAt.NONE;
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setPercentage(float percent) {
        //100 % = 360 degree

        float angle = convertToRadians(90);
        angle -= convertToRadians(percent * 360 / 100);

        float len = this.getWidth() > this.getHeight() ? this.getWidth() : this.getHeight();
        float dy = (float) (Math.sin(angle) * len);
        float dx = (float) (Math.cos(angle) * len);
        Vector2 line = new Vector2(center.x + dx, center.y + dy);

        Vector2 v = IntersectPoint(line);

        if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.TOP) {
            if (v.x >= this.getWidth() / 2) {
                fv = new float[]{
                        center.x,
                        center.y,
                        centerTop.x,
                        centerTop.y,
                        leftTop.x,
                        leftTop.y,
                        leftBottom.x,
                        leftBottom.y,
                        rightBottom.x,
                        rightBottom.y,
                        rightTop.x,
                        rightTop.y,
                        v.x,
                        v.y
                };
            } else {
                fv = new float[]{
                        center.x,
                        center.y,
                        centerTop.x,
                        centerTop.y,
                        v.x,
                        v.y
                };
            }
        } else if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.BOTTOM) {
            fv = new float[]{
                    center.x,
                    center.y,
                    centerTop.x,
                    centerTop.y,
                    leftTop.x,
                    leftTop.y,
                    leftBottom.x,
                    leftBottom.y,
                    v.x,
                    v.y
            };

        } else if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.LEFT) {
            fv = new float[]{
                    center.x,
                    center.y,
                    centerTop.x,
                    centerTop.y,
                    leftTop.x,
                    leftTop.y,
                    v.x,
                    v.y
            };

        } else if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.RIGHT) {
            fv = new float[]{
                    center.x,
                    center.y,
                    centerTop.x,
                    centerTop.y,
                    leftTop.x,
                    leftTop.y,
                    leftBottom.x,
                    leftBottom.y,
                    rightBottom.x,
                    rightBottom.y,
                    v.x,
                    v.y
            };

        } else // if (intersectAt == IntersectAt.NONE)
        {
            fv = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if (fv == null) return;
        batch.end();
        drawMe();
        batch.begin();
    }


    public void drawMe() {

        EarClippingTriangulator e = new EarClippingTriangulator();
        ShortArray sv = e.computeTriangles(fv);

        PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(texture, fv, sv.toArray());

        PolygonSprite poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
        poly.setSize(PROGRESS_WIDTH,PROGRESS_HEIGHT);
        poly.setPosition(posX,posY);
        poly.setOrigin(poly.getOriginX(), poly.getOriginY());
        poly.setRotation(this.getRotation());
        poly.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        polyBatch.begin();
        poly.draw(polyBatch);
        polyBatch.end();
    }


    float convertToDegrees(float angleInRadians) {
        float angleInDegrees = angleInRadians * 57.2957795f;
        return angleInDegrees;
    }

    float convertToRadians(float angleInDegrees) {
        float angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * 0.0174532925f;
        return angleInRadians;
    }
}
```

and my init function:

```
 ProgressCircle sprite;

 private void initCircleProgress() {

    Group group = new Group();
    Image downBackground = new Image(atlas.findRegion("progressBackground"));
    downBackground.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    downBackground.setSize(USER_SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH/5,USER_SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH/5);
    downBackground.setPosition(10,USER_SCREEN_SIZE_HEIGHT-(2*downBackground.getHeight()+20));

    sprite = new ProgressCircle(atlas.findRegion("progressBackground"), pbatch,
            downBackground.getWidth(),downBackground.getHeight(),downBackground.getX(),downBackground.getY());
    sprite.setSize(downBackground.getWidth(),downBackground.getHeight());
    sprite.setSize(downBackground.getX(),downBackground.getY());
    Image label = new Image(atlas.findRegion("progressBackground"));
    label.setSize(downBackground.getWidth()*0.8f,downBackground.getHeight()*0.8f);
    label.setPosition(downBackground.getX()+(downBackground.getWidth()-label.getWidth())/2,
            downBackground.getY()+(downBackground.getHeight()-label.getHeight())/2);
    label.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    group.addActor(downBackground);
    group.addActor(sprite);
    group.addActor(label);
    group.setPosition(10,GAME_SIZE_HEIGHT-(group.getHeight()+20));
    stage.addActor(group);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a circular gradient to [mask](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Masking) out the desired parts.

[image]

Incrementing the masking values over time will result in a circular motion.

As you can see in the [link to masking](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Masking) there are several methods to achieve this. A stencil buffer would be a good choice but can result in jaggy edges. Writing your own shader would be perfect but kinda hard [if you never wrote a shader](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson4). You can also try to parse both pix maps and decide what pixels to draw while looping through both pixmaps. If the masking image and your source have equal texture space you can do this in one loop so it would not be that much slower then a shader and whatever works for you is a good solution, you can always optimize later.