# SVG Circle Stroke Origin

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

I'm having trouble describing the issue, but here goes:

I'm trying to make a SVG circle progress bar and I've found a perfect example of what I want to do without any third part libraries like snap:

http://codepen.io/JMChristensen/pen/Ablch

The problem is that I'm having real issues with changing the origin of the stroke. As you'll notice if you try it out, the origin is on the right hand side. I need it to come from the top.

Now, I'm a developer, so I've tried myself, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. If I change the stroke-dasharray attribute the stroke won't match the percentage set in stroke-dashoffset.

I understand it all comes down to math with the stroke-dasharray value, but I don't quite understand what to do.

The dashoffset is calculated like this:

```
                var pct = ((100-val)/100)*(Math.PI*(r*2));
```

And there has to be some kind of correlation between that and the standard dasharray value 565.48. There's no mention of it anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202920/circular-radial-progress-bar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to the 2nd `<circle ...></circle>` in the SVG:

```
transform="rotate(270,100,100)"
```

[Demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DGchk)

Comment: Another option is to use CSS: `transform-origin:center center; transform:rotate(-90deg);`

Comment: The first number "270" means 270 degrees.
The second and the third one are numbers which defines the transform-origin

Comment: You should click "edit" and add that information to the answer :)

Comment: I facepalmed when I realized how easy this was. How could I not see this? Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your last bit of inquiry:

> And there has to be some kind of correlation between that and the standard dasharray value 565.48. There's no mention of it anywhere.

Well, π(r*2) or simply 2πr will give you the circumference of a circle, which in turn gives you the appropriate value for the dash-array that completes the circle.

For example:

Your SVG circle has a radius of 90.

**2π(90)** = **565.48**, therefore your dash-array will be **565.48**.

If your radius is 45...

**2π(45)** = **282.74**, so your dash-array will be **282.74**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that really cleared it up for me!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for 270deg rotation:

```
transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,0,200)"
```